# Equivalência da função GEN_ID() do Firebird no ORACLE

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, oracle, firebird, oracle11g

Fala galera, estou iniciando aprendizagem com BD Oracle, antes eu usava o firebird. Porém estou tendo um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver. Eu não consigo incluir um novo pais pelo sistema (java), se eu inserir pelo SQLDeveloper, ele aparece na consulta. O erro que aparece quando tento incluir é o seguinte:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: a tabela ou view não existe

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:852)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1477)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:392)
    at bd.Conexao.pegaGenerator(Conexao.java:50)


(...)
```

a linha que o erro me indica, é :

```
public static Integer pegaGenerator(String generator) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Statement st = Conexao.getConexao().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT GEN_ID(" + generator + ", 1) FROM RDB$DATABASE");
            rs.next();
            return rs.getInt(1);
        } 

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível obter o generator!");
            return null;
        } 
    }
```

A tabela no Oracle eu criei assim:

```
CREATE TABLE Pais
(
ID_Pais INTEGER NOT NULL,
Nome_Pais VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
Sigla_Pais VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
Status_Pais CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ID_Pais PRIMARY KEY (ID_Pais) 
);
```

e pela ferramenta fiz a trigger

Comment: Se você fizer "SELECT GEN_ID(" + generator + ", 1) FROM PAIS" não funciona?

Comment: eu fazia assim no firebird pra ficar orientado, ai ele pegava todas tabelas, esse código eu não preciso repetir.

Comment: voce pode fazer um `select MAX([coluna]) + 1 from [tabela]` mas acredito que o Oracle nao tenha uma funcao `GEN_ID()`  igual ao Firebird - a quesito de info. o equivalente no oracle da tabela dummy do Firebird `RDB$DATABASE` é `DUAL`

Comment: Ah, acho que agora entendi (não conheço Firebird). Você quer gerar um ID para poder usar em `ID_Pais`. É isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Firebird existem os [generators](http://firebirdsql.org/manual/generatorguide.html). Já no Oracle existem as [sequences](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/database-performance/abordando-o-uso-sequencias-oracle-495861-ptb.html).

Para criá-la você deve fazer:

```
create sequence seq_tabela_exemplo;
```

Inclusive pode definir várias configurações:

```
create sequence seq_tabela_exemplo
   start with 5
   increment by -1
   maxvalue 5
   minvalue 0
   nocache
   cycle;
```

Para obter o próximo valor, execute:

```
select seq_tabela_exemplo.nextval from dual;
```

Para mais detalhes, consulte a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314).

Comment: eu tentei → ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT SEQ_ID_(" + sequence + ", 1) .NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");   Porém da erro dizendo:  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "SEQ_ID_": identificador inválido.  Minha sintaxe esta errada ?

Comment: O certo é "SELECT " + sequence + ".NEXTVAL FROM DUAL"

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado.